# How to resolve Attribute error in Python?

Tags: python, python-descriptors

I am learning Descriptors in python. I am trying the code , but getting below mentioned Attribute error.

AttributeError: 'celciusDescriptor' object has no attribute '_celciusDescriptor__fahrenheit'

I am trying to get the output as (32,0) which is (Fahrenheit, celcius), by getting the temperature in Fahrenheit.

'''

```
  class celciusDescriptor:
        def __get__(self, obj, owner):
            tempc = self.__fahrenheit
            celcius = (tempc - 32)*(5/9)
            return self.celcius
        def __set__(self, obj, value):
            tempcelc = (value - 32)*(5/9)
            return tempcelc
    
           
    class Temperature:
        celcius = celciusDescriptor()
        def __init__(self, fahrenheit):
            self.fahrenheit = fahrenheit
            
    
    t1 = Temperature(32)
    t1.fahrenheit
    t1.celcius
```

'''

Comment: You are reading from `self.__fahrenheit`, but at no point did you ever assign to it.  How were you expecting that to work?

Comment: Instance attributes starting with `__` are subject to name mangeling.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one pattern for doing this (by the way, class names typically start with upper case). There is only a need to keep a Celsius or a Fahrenheit value as one can be computed from the other. In this case I am using a class `CelsiusDescriptor` to keep the Celsius value (even though you construct a `Temperature` instance with a Fahrenheit value), since this is the way you have it. I then use ordinary properties for getting and setting the Fahrenheit value. The actual Celsius value is stored in the `Temperature` object's internal `__dict__` attribute, where its other attributes are normally stored. This descriptor also does type enforcement.

```
class CelsiusDescriptor:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __get__(self, instance, cls):
        if instance is None:
            return self
        else:
            return instance.__dict__[self.name]

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        if not isinstance(value, (int, float)):
            raise TypeError('Expected an int or a float')
        instance.__dict__[self.name] = value

    def __delete__(self, instance):
        del instance.__dict__[self.name]


class Temperature:
    celsius = CelsiusDescriptor('celsius') # a class attribute

    def __init__(self, fahrenheit):
        self.celsius = (fahrenheit-32) * 5/9;

    @property
    def fahrenheit(self):
        return self.celsius*9/5 + 32

    @fahrenheit.setter
    def fahrenheit(self, fahrenheit):
        self.celsius = (fahrenheit-32) * 5/9;

t = Temperature(32)
print(t.fahrenheit, t.celsius)
t.celsius = 100
print(t.fahrenheit, t.celsius)
t.fahrenheit = -40
print(t.fahrenheit, t.celsius)
```

Prints:

```
32.0 0.0
212.0 100
-40.0 -40.0
```

Comment: Thanks much..I will work on it.  Between, could you please suggest me any good material/website to understand the class concepts in Python better?

Comment: I would just suggest that you Google "Best Python books" and "Understanding Python classes". But other than that there's no one source I could recommend above others. You might also do a search for "Download Python Cookbook". Version 3 is available for free and contains lots of useful things including the method used in answering your question for enforcing that an that attribute can only be assigned a specific type (which wasn't actually your requirement, but did make sense to enforce).

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
class celciusDescriptor:
        def __get__(self, tempc):
            tempc = None
            self.celcius = (tempc - 32)*(5/9)
            print(self.celcius)
        def __set__(self, value):
            tempcelc = (value - 32)*(5/9)
            print(tempcelc)
    
           
class Temperature:
        celcius = celciusDescriptor()
        def __init__(self, fahrenheit):
            self.fahrenheit = fahrenheit
            print(self.fahrenheit)
            
    
t1 = Temperature(32)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).